# PySpark get only first element from array column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyspark

I have an Array column in PySpark which looks something like this

```
Parsed

[/level1/level2, /level2/level3/level4, /level1/level2]
[/level1/level2, /level2/level3]
[/level1/level2, /level1/level2/level3, /level1/level2]
[/level1/level2, /level1/level2/level3, /level1/level2]
```

I want something like this

```
Parsed
[level1, level2, level1]
[level1, level2]
[level1, level1, level1]
```

Sample row

```
Parsed
[/president/vicepresident/seniormanager, /president/seniormanager, /manager/teamlead]
```

Expected output

```
Parsed
[ president, president, manager]
```

Basically, I want only the first level in each element of array

My approach

```
df.filter(col("Parsed")
    .rlike("/Level/")
  ).show()
```

Comment: share sample row and expected out, spark version... etc

Comment: is it a nested json  or csv ,please write all necessary it is very difficult?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach in [pyspark](/questions/tagged/pyspark).

```
# input data
data_sdf = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data_ls).toDF(['arr_col'])

# +-------------------------------------------------------+
# |arr_col                                                |
# +-------------------------------------------------------+
# |[/level1/level2, /level2/level3/level4, /level1/level2]|
# |[/level1/level2, /level2/level3]                       |
# |[/level1/level2, /level1/level2/level3, /level1/level2]|
# |[/level1/level2, /level1/level2/level3, /level1/level2]|
# +-------------------------------------------------------+

data_sdf. \
    withColumn('rn', func.row_number().over(wd.orderBy(func.lit(1)))). \
    withColumn('arr_col_exploded', func.explode('arr_col')). \
    withColumn('arr_col_exp_split', func.split('arr_col_exploded', '\/')). \
    withColumn('first_element', func.col('arr_col_exp_split')[1]). \
    groupBy('rn', 'arr_col'). \
    agg(func.collect_list('first_element').alias('first_element_arr')). \
    show(truncate=False)

# +---+-------------------------------------------------------+------------------------+
# |rn |arr_col                                                |first_element_arr       |
# +---+-------------------------------------------------------+------------------------+
# |1  |[/level1/level2, /level2/level3/level4, /level1/level2]|[level1, level2, level1]|
# |2  |[/level1/level2, /level2/level3]                       |[level1, level2]        |
# |3  |[/level1/level2, /level1/level2/level3, /level1/level2]|[level1, level1, level1]|
# |4  |[/level1/level2, /level1/level2/level3, /level1/level2]|[level1, level1, level1]|
# +---+-------------------------------------------------------+------------------------+
```

The `rn` is to help in grouping, if there are duplicate input arrays. The idea is to `explode` the input array and then `split` the exploded elements which creates an array of the elements that were delimited by `'/'`. Once split, we can pull out the second element (which is actually the first element) as the first will be a null (due to the first `'/'`). Finally, use `collect_list` to create an array of the first elements.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`pd.DataFrame.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) to explode the rows containing `list of string` then using [`pd.Series.str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) you can get the first data and then we can group the data back on index by using [`pd.DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html).

```
dict_ = { 'levels' : [['/level1/level2', '/level2/level3/level4', '/level1/level2'],
['/level1/level2', '/level2/level3'],
['/level1/level2', '/level1/level2/level3', '/level1/level2'],
['/level1/level2', '/level1/level2/level3', '/level1/level2']]}

df = pd.DataFrame(dict_)

df['levels'].explode().str.split('/', expand=True)[1].reset_index().groupby('index')[1].apply(list)
```

##### Output

which gives us the expected output

```
0    [level1, level2, level1]
1            [level1, level2]
2    [level1, level1, level1]
3    [level1, level1, level1]
Name: 1, dtype: object
```